# border 0 still leaves a black circle in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have a circle that looks like

```
    margin:200,
    height: '10px',
    width: '10px',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    border:'0',
    display: 'inline-block',
    box-shadow: '0px 0px 10px 80px #000'
```

i've set the border into 0, but there is still a black circle. How do i remove that? [image]

'None' or 'Hidden' doesn't work either

This is only a problem in firefox, chrome and safari is good

An live example can be found here. If you open it in firefox you will see a circle near the center. This didn't happen in Chrome or Safari.
https://codepen.io/jianyi-ren/pen/MqzdjP

Comment: What black circle do you mean? Do you mean the one in the center? Do you mean the "background" around the red thing? Also: You should probably make a jsfiddle or a codepen which shows the error.

Comment: the one in the center.  Thanks for the suggestions. will go to make the codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rendering issue with firefox. Use a fake parent around the child to solve this issue. Check the working codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxrLGb

```
#fakediv {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 100px;
   background-color: #888888;
}
```